# Shapefile gets loaded in SHTML, but fails in HTML

Tags: javascript, leaflet, shapefile

The following code successfully loads shapefile into leaflet when I use SHTML, but it fails if I use HTML (which I have to use). It does not return any errors, the shapefile object initializes, but the shapes are not shown.
Any idea how to approach it? How am I to find out what's going on?

```
// so far so good

var m = L.map('map').setView([47.5757798, 13.656677], 7);
var watercolor = L.tileLayer('http://maps.wien.gv.at/basemap/bmapgrau/normal/google3857/{z}/{y}/{x}.png', {
  attribution: 'TEST'
}).addTo(m);

// here the problem begins

var shpfile = new L.Shapefile('/shapes/Layer_A.zip', {  
  style: function(feature1) {
    return {
      color:"#ff0000",
      fillColor:"#ff0000",
      fillOpacity:.50
    };
  }
});
shpfile.addTo(m);

// it never gets this far, the console does not show the message

shpfile.once("data:loaded", function() {
  console.log("finished loaded shapefile");
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by SHTML?

Comment: Also, any reason why you're not attaching an event handler to the `data:error` event?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the raw SHTML file? Odds are, you have a critical directive in there that is not being processed when the file is HTML

Comment: @IvanSanchez: SHTML is an extension that tells the server that the HTML contains SSI directives that should be processed before the file is served

Comment: The file you're loading appears to be neither HTML nor SHTML - it's a zip file. Would you be able to explain the problem a little better?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use 4D as a web server. It sends either 'SHTML' or 'HTML' (or any other type) as a response. The content of 2 files is identical. But the leaflet loads the shape from zip files and displays it (screenshot https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wsurl4Mvg67hMKs37raVe3qLMEGYLU4T) when 'SHTML' file is sent, and it does not in case of 'HTML' (screenshot https://drive.google.com/open?id=199bc8S__m5bLskjg5KWaiiFJCDxelQUP)
You've given me a hint though. I'll try 'data:error', perhaps it'll help.

Comment: 'data:error' does not change anything. Seems like no error is generated.

Comment: In what way are you 'using' HTML or SHTML? All you're doing is fetching a binary zip file.

Comment: JS code fragment is a part of an HTML (SHTML) page. I send the page as a response from the server. On the client side JS code executes. It creates a leaflet, loads map and then opens the ZIP, that contains shapes.

Comment: But my main question - is there a way to debug it? If I find out what happens with the ZIP shape, I'll fix it.

Comment: Solved! It was a bloody path problem. JS library in a wrong place.
Thanks to everybody, who tried to help!